# How to check if all elements of array are filled in Python

Tags: python

I am making a To Do List app in Python using Arrays or Lists. I want to check if the array containing all "to-do tasks" is full or not. If it is full I would then inform the user that the list is full. **I am still a beginner.**

```
todo_list = ["1.)", "2.)", "3.)", "4.)", "5.)", "6.)", "7.)", "8.)", "9.)", "10.)"]
def addTask(taskName):

  '''
  this is a global variable to keep track of what index the last task was 
  placed in.
  '''


  global x
  x = int(x)
  num = x + 1
  num = int(num)
  taskName = str(taskName)

  '''
  This is what I tried to make the program start from the beginning if the 
  list was full.
  '''

  if x > list_length:
    x = 0
    todo_list[0] = None


  todo_list[x] = str(num) + ".) " + taskName
  x = x+1

  print("Done!")
  main()
```

Comment: Hi, I'd recommend you to read through [this (whole) article](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#more-control-flow-tools).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you saying that you've limited the number of possible tasks to 10? and if each one has a task attached then the list should notify the user it's full?

If so, you know that an empty task is "10.)" so at max it's length is 4 (4 characters), so if any items length is less than or equal to 4 then it's empty

```
for task in todo_list:
    if len(task) > 4:
        print('Todo list is full')
        break
    else:
        print('Todo list is full')
```

**Can I also advise of a better way** to create the todo list? Use a dictionary.

```
todo_list = {'clean cat':'incomplete', 'buy milk':'complete'}
```

and to add a new task is easy!

```
todo_list['learn python'] = 'incomplete'
```

and to update a task is even easier!

```
todo_list['clean cat'] = 'complete'
```

Here is how I would do it:

```
todo_list = {}

if len(todo_list) == 10:
    print('Sorry, list is full!')
else:
    task_name = input('Task name: ')
    todo_list[task_name] = 'incomplete'

print(todo_list)
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question and teaching me another way to make lists

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to define `todo_list` with numbering. Just define the maximum size of `todo_list` and check if length of `todo_list` is bigger than maximum size.

```
todo_list = list()
MAX_SIZE = 10

add_task(taskName:str):
    if len(todo_list) >= MAX_SIZE:
        # code you want to run when todo_list is full
    else:
        todo_list.append("{}.) {}".format(len(todo_list)+1, taskName))
```

Comment: You answered my question too, but @Ari Victor also told me another way to to make lists thank you for the answer though!